# Best way to test a method that works with streams

Tags: java, junit

I got this method

```
    void sort(InputStream in, OutputStream out, Comparator<?> comparator) throws IOException;
```

that sorts the input stream (XML data) in the output stream (same format) according to the provided comparator.

Since I am a beginner with Junit, how would you test this method? It would be great if you can provide some code snippet.

Comment: What is the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: That's a good start, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I've created two streams this way
inputStream = new FileInputStream(PATH_PREFIX + SOURCE_FILE);
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(PATH_PREFIX + TARGET_FILE);

But I have no idea how to assert that they are equal.

Comment: Pass a ByteArrayOutputStream to your method, then get the resulting byte array: that's the actual output. Read the expected output file to a byte array: that's the expected output. Then compare the two byte arrays.

Comment: Thanks, can you please show me the code please?

Comment: No. That's not how it works here. If you just want code instead of answers and explanations, then hire a developer.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and sorry for having asked such a stupid question. I got the test working. Thanks a lot for your hint!

Comment: I got a question. I am  doing this now 

  byte[] expected = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(...));
  Assert.assertEquals(expected, outputStreamBuffer);

Comment: That's not a question. But I see what you're asking. http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(byte[],%20byte[])

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBNizet. I got another question: is there any way to remove the white space in order to compare the actual content and not its formatting?

Comment: There's probably a way to configure your XML marshaller to avoid generating white-spaces. Another solution would be to parse the expected and actual XML to some data structure, and compere the data structures. Of to query both XMLs using XPath or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unittests in general test *public observable behavior*

in your case it is the interaction with the two streams.

- create *mocks* for the two steams (usually I'd suggest to use a mocking framework but there are some simple implementations in the standard lib quite suitable for this purpose...)
- Configure the inputStream to return data in false order.
- check that the output stream got data in correct order.

This could look like this:

```
public class StreamsTest {

    InputStream inputStream;

    OutputStream outputStream;

    @Test
    public void sort_givenShuffledXml_returnsSortedXml() {
        // arrange
        YourClassUnderTest cut = new YourClassUnderTest();
        Comparator<?> comparator = new YourRealComparatorImpl();
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("unsortedXML".getBytes());
        outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // act
        cut.sort(inputStream, outputStream, comparator);

        //assert
        Assert.assertThat(outputStream.toString(),CoreMatchers.equalTo("sortedXml"));
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Can you please explain the class CoreMatchers?

Comment: @user3727540 there is a public API for this class: http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html